# Re-using Boost's timer objects

Tags: c++, boost, timer

I modify the code from Boost's Timer 2 tutorial [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html)
 for a periodic printout:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

void print(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/)
{
    static int i = 0;
    i++;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        boost::asio::io_context io;
        boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(1));

        t.async_wait(&print);
        t.wait();
        io.run();
    }
}
```

What I don't get is if I take the first two lines outside of while(1), it will not work properly.  Is there a way to create these objects and reuse them?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to schedule the next timer event with

- `expires_at` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/expires_at.html
- or `expires_from_now` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/expires_from_now.html

So, like:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void print(boost::system::error_code ec) {
    static int i = 0;
    if (ec != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
        i++;
    }
    std::cout << i << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io);

    while (1) {
        t.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
        t.async_wait(&print);

        if (io.stopped()) { io.reset(); }
        io.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample code.  I thought I had my problem solved.  It was not.

Answer (score 1):

OK, that part is apparently in Timer 3 tutorial.  Also, the documentations of 1.66 has missing info.  Gotta change to 1.65 to see it.

Comment: What docs. What is missing. How does this answer the question? You don't even mention how you can re-use the timer. And you fail to address the fact that `reset()` needs to be called if `io` runs out of work.

Comment: @sehe, the 1.66 documentations page I was looking at has its codes missing.  Change the 1_66 to 1_65 in the link to get to the old page.  How can I notify the people at Boost to address this problem?

Comment: This is not an answer, regardless of whether there's missing information in the docs.

Comment: @CaTx Don't bother notifying the people at boost if you can't provide the link I asked for.

Comment: Here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer3.html

Comment: Good spot. I see what you mean now. That must be quickbook fail. I'd mention it at the boost mailing list, or file an issue at Chris Kohlhoff's Asio github

Comment: Done!  Issue created.

Comment: I did provide sehe with the info.  He acknowledged it.  How is that not clear?